# LLDB RPC server freezes app

Tags: xcode, lldb

For the past months I have not been able to debug macOS or iOS apps through Xcode. What happens is the following:

1. Build and run app from Xcode.
2. Xcode says app is running, but no app has appeared and no debug output from app either.
3. Kill the process `lldb-rpc-server`.
4. App appears and runs as normal, but Xcode is no longer debugging.
5. Start a new debugging session by attaching it to the app's process.
6. App freezes again, until `lldb-rpc-server` is killed.

[This](http://www.openradar.me/33277953) OpenRadar has the same description.

I have tried re-installing Xcode (including command-line tools), but it didn't help. Any ideas?

---

**Xcode:** Version 9.3.1 (9E501)

**MacOS:** 10.13.4 (17E199)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this was that I had installed a GDB/LLDB-extension called [Voltron](https://github.com/snare/voltron). I was unaware that the installation also created/modified the `.lldbinit` in the home folder. Removing this file fixed the issue. See also [this issue](https://github.com/snare/voltron/issues/228) for Voltron.

Got some very good help from Apple.

Comment: Good lord, this was the last thing to think about, and of course removing it from `.lldbinit` fixed the debug sessions! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had received this warning msg when device was locked and I was running app on device, so when device is unlocked this warning goes